# node js blog, hide content (for non logged in users)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, stylus

I am working on a blog in node.js and I need to know if there is a way to hide content, like 'edit', 'delete' and 'new post' buttons, for users that are not logged in? I could redirect 'guests' to pages without those buttons, but that seems kinda dumb. This is a login method I found, and it works, but how do I use this 'req.session.user = username;' in a good way?

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password).digest('base64');   

    r.connect( {host: 'localhost', port: 28015}, function(err, conn) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection = conn;

        r.db("app").table("user").filter({username: username, password: hash}).run(conn, function(err, cursor){
            if (err) throw err;

            cursor.toArray(function(err, result){
                if(result.length == 0){
                    res.render("index", {msg: "No user with that name"})
                    }
                else{
                    console.log(username);
                    req.session.user = username;
                    res.redirect("index");
                    //res.render("menu");
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

I am working in node.js with express, jade and stylus.
I hope you understand, and just tell me if I need to post any more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution may be to set a flag on `res.locals` that you use in your views. You'd initialize say, `res.locals.loggedIn = false;` somewhere early on in your middleware stack if they are logged in or set it to `true` if they are (e.g. a session exists with some information showing they have successfully authenticated before).

Then in your view you just do something like `if (loggedIn) { /* show buttons */ }`

Comment: I am not great with html/css (jade, stylus), how would code like that look like, it sounds great.. I understand the 'res.locals.loggedIn = false/true', but to show buttons I am unsure

Comment: The front page of [jade's homepage](http://jade-lang.com/) shows an example of an if-else statement in the template. So swap out `youAreUsingJade` in their example with `loggedIn`.